# Changing ubuntu one installation folder in windows

Tags: installation, windows, default

I changed my windows default programs(x86) folder to another partition, I have all my programs installed there, it's in D:, but the automatic ubuntuone installation puts the program in C:, obviously, when my windows looks for ubuntuone on D: (where it's automatically directed) it doesn't find it.

After installation I have to change the path to the program but it keeps giving me error messages and it's not working properly.

Is there any way I can change the default installation path?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the Ubuntu One installation folder and run this command on cmd:

```
mklink /D {old ubuntu one path} {new ubuntu one path}
```